# Image based CSS Dropdown menus

Tags: css, navigation

I'm building a website, and would like to make aa navigation bar with submenus. My menu items are entirely image based. I have an image for each item, and each item hover. I'm just not sure how to go about doing it this way, I only know how to make one without use of images. Thanks

Comment: Also you should look into css sprites for your images, so you don't get flicker on each image load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the same thing like you would do with textbased navigation. after you've finished set your `li a {text-indent:-9999px}` this will hide the text description (this is anyway nice to have for mobile and seo), now create an image-sprite with your images and position them nicely with in css with the `background-position` property.